# How to solve this coupled system of ODEs: $x_1'' = x_2 $, $x_2'' = -x_1 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a simple seeming system, described as below :

${x_1}'' =  x_2 $

${x_2}'' =  -x_1 $

Can some one give me the steps to proceed, so that I can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Mhenni Benghorbal good suggestion, we find $x_1''''=x_2''=-x_1$. The characteristics of $x_1''''=-x_1$ are the roots of $r^4+1$. That is $r= e^{\pm 3i\pi/4}, e^{\pm i\pi/4}$. The general solution thus is $$x_1=\exp(t/\sqrt{2})\left(a\,\cos(t/\sqrt{2})+b\,\sin(t/\sqrt{2})\right)+\exp(-t/\sqrt{2})\left(c\,\cos(t/\sqrt{2})+d\,\sin(t/\sqrt{2})\right).$$

From then, it is easy to find $x_2$ using the equation $x_2=x_1''$.

---

EDIT : Corrected the solution as per the comment below.

Comment: Shouldn't that expression have "$\exp(t/\sqrt{2})$" and "$\exp(-t/\sqrt{2})$" instead of "$\exp(1/\sqrt{2})$" and "$\exp(--1/\sqrt{2})$"?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: let $z:=x_1+i x_2$. What is $z''$?

Comment: If solved this way, note that the two constants of integration should generally be assumed as complex (i.e. four _real_ constants).

Answer (score 2):

**hint:** you can use [Laplace transform techniques](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eekeQWtluqg). Another approach is to eliminate $x_1$ or $x_2$ from one of the equations by differentiating to get equation in $x_1$ or $x_2$ only.

Answer (score 2):

**Another Hint**: $x_1'''' = x_2'' = -x_1$. This gives you a fourth order linear homogeneous ODE.

And yes, I did just use four primes to denote the fourth derivative.